# Symfony2 - Multiple slug in one route

Tags: php, symfony, routes, slug

In Symfony is it possible to access a controller through a route that potentially can contain indefinite number of slug, taking advantage from internal routing system?

e.g.

```
my_route:
    pattern: /{slug_parent}/{slug_child}/{slug_nephew}/{slug_...}/...
```

as

```
www.mydomain.com/math/arithmetic/fractions
```

**but also**

```
www.mydomain.com/tech/android
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Routing for category tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297762/routing-for-category-tree)

Comment: @cheesemacfly Yep! working for me.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but instead of creating routes in config YML I would recommend to use @Route annotations. Add annotations in the controller class, like this:

```
 /**
     * @Route("/{slug_parent}/{slug_child}")
     * @Route("/{slug_parent}/{slug_child}/{slug_nephew}/")
     * @Route("/{slug_parent}/{slug_child}/{slug_nephew}/{slug_...}/")
     */
    public function yourControllerAction()
    {
...
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html