# Category tree in url

Tags: symfony

i'm need create nice url for category or product. As example: `category3` has parent category `category2`, `category2` has parent `category1`, path to `category3` must be http://site.name/category1/category2/category3; path to products from category3 must be http://site.name/category1/category2/category3/produc_tname. How i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should create (on my opinion) twig extension for it. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html  Where to calculate\create url you need. So basically you should create your own 'path()' function in twig.

Comment: I think need create custom action with empty route (/.*) and parse url there, but maybe exists more nice solution...

Comment: You can use container in Twig Extension so you can do it there (and use everywhere you need).

Answer (score 0):

First you need slugs for your categories than i would recommend you Doctrine2 extension: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md

and **TreeSlugHandler**: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/annotations.md#gedmo-sluggable

Comment: I'm using gedmo, but this funcitonal does not solution for this issue. I think, need to look towards routing